# Updating the main table row using another table which have multiple rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables with common column id

```
Table A:
ID   value1    value2    value3
------------------------------------        
 1     0         0        0

Table B:
ID    value_type      value   
--------------------------------------          
1     value1          0.01  
2     value2          0.02
3     value3          0.03
```

I want to update table A value using table b value,

```
Final Output :

ID   value1    value2    value3
-----------------------------------------
1     0.01       0.02      0.03
```

Can anyone show me how to write a query and fetch the result as above, Thanks very much! I have tried join, pivot. all result nothing.

Comment: What happens if `Table A` has more than one `ID` value?

Comment: Might be ID column having value 1 for all records of  Table B in given example. Please confirm.

Comment: yes there is multiple value in table A as well as table B with common column ID

Comment: Not according to the sample data you've posted. In table A you only posted one record and it table B every record have a different value in the ID column. Please [edit] your question to resolve the conflict between the text and the sample data. While you're at it, you should read the excellent post over on meta.dba.stackexchange called [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). and convert the sample data to DDL+DML statements.

Answer (score 1):

A quick (but not scalable) solution would be to use an update statement with a join to a derived table with conditional aggrigation:

```
UPDATE T
SET value1 = v1,
    value2 = v2,
    value3 = v3
FROM TableA T
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 1 As ID
           MAX(CASE WHEN value_type = 'value1' THEN value END) As v1,
           MAX(CASE WHEN value_type = 'value2' THEN value END) As v2,
           MAX(CASE WHEN value_type = 'value3' THEN value END) As v3
    FROM TableB
) V
    ON T.ID = V.ID
```

Comment: there are no fixed column numbers in table it is possible to fetch dynamic?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify your needs exactly. Also, be sure that the sample data matches the text. Before you do that, anything I'll write would be a guess.

Comment: @Thebeginner . . . This answers the question that you have asked, which is specifically about updating three columns in the first table.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  You should be aware that tables do not have dynamic columns, so be careful about how you phrase your next question.

Answer (score 0):

using pivot we can do this

Since iam storing data into one table and after that only iam doinn updation

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.value_type)
            FROM #b c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT rn as id , '  + (@cols) + ' into dynamictable  from 
            (
                select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID ) AS RN
                from #b
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(VALUEE)
                for VALUE_TYPE in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
          '


exec(@query)
UPDATE T
SET T.value1 = V.value1,
    T.value2 = V.value2,
    T.value3 = V.value3
FROM #a T
JOIN 
(SELECT   id ,MAX(VALUE1)VALUE1 , MAX(VALUE2)VALUE2, MAX(VALUE3)VALUE3 
FROM  dynamictable
GROUP BY id
) V
    ON T.ID = V.ID
```

[image]

Comment: there are no fixed column numbers in table it is possible to fetch dynamic?

Comment: @Thebeginner then you have to use dynamic pivot

Comment: can u please help me?

Comment: @Thebeginner this will not be possible even dynamic query also because we can do upto pivot multiple columns but the thing is we cant update the required output into table1 since table is having only 3 columns so i can give code upto dynamic pivot only